# Spring Rest: when pathVariable matches multiple entities should spring return a list or throw error

Tags: java, spring, rest, restful-url, spring-rest

Say, a persons collection contain more than one person with the same first and last name. (i.e ex: more than one person with name Andrew Thomas). What will/should be the response of the below rest request

`/persons/{firstName}/{lastName}`  ie. `/persons/andrew/thomas`
or

`/persons/{firstName lastName}` i.e `/persons/andrew thomas` (not sure if spaces are allowed in path variable)

Now since a db query will return more than one record, what should I expect (or what is the correct response to return)

Comment: If a query returns more than one record you should expect `List<Person>`

Comment: The API URL depends on what you prefers. For example, if *firstName* and *lastName* are different field in your DB criteria, the first case fit better. If they are the same field, then the second case should be used. To avoid issues use encoding/deconding of URL parameters. The retult should be a collection, like a list, for example.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends completly on the return type of your method or what you are returning as a output of this API.**

If you have returned only person object as

```
public Person getperson(){}
```

it can return only single person object .
if you get multiple result at this instant so as the return type can return only single object it will give error.

So if you are getting multiple object with same first name and last name you should use return type as list as

```
public List<Person> getperson(){}
```

> In the above case it will work either you get one result many result
>   or no result.

Thanks hope it will help you out

Comment: so, if I am not querying on primary key, then I assume it might be safe to return a list, as one can never be sure if the query returns a single entity or a list of entities. Right ???

Comment: Absolutely right . when you are not sure weather you will get single output or multiple use list only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not searching on a `primary or unique key`, the return type of REST API should always be `List`.

Comment: i think this answers. tx